# Отключение DHCP

Tags: роутер

Стоят два роутера (TP1 и TP2) работают в режиме WDS, на TP2 отключён DHCP и прописан основной шлюз IP роутера TP1, все цепляющиеся на TP2 естественно получают настройки сети после того как их передаст TP1, это занимает 10-20 секунд , я пробовал отключить DHCP на обоих роутерах при это задав статические IP адрес на wi-fi подключении ноутбука  коннект с точкой 2-4 секунды, Вопрос в следующем, снижает ли отключение DHCP на роутере нагрузку на сам роутер учитывая что общее количество беспроводных клиентов 16-18  или она не значительна?!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Незначительна.

Задержка происходит из-за самого протокола DHCP и скорости передачи, сам роутер напрягается один раз в момент назначения адреса и переназначения (через 8 часов или 1 час обычно, всё в настройках DHCP-сервера)